# AWS S3 thumbnail "Access denied"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I followed [Tutorial: Using an Amazon S3 trigger to create thumbnail images - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html) to create a thumbnail for my images.

However, when I try to access the images in bucket-resized I get an `Access Denied`.

Comment: Are you accessing using the image URL? These thumbmails are supposed to be public?

Comment: @OmarRosadio yes I am using the image URL. I'm not 100 per sure if they should be. But I need to access them on my mobile app. I am building something similar to instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial does *not* create 'public' objects.

If you want the resized objects to be public, you would either need to:

- Create a **Bucket Policy** on the 'resized' bucket that grants `s3:GetObject` access for the bucket (see [Bucket policy examples - Granting read-only permission to an anonymous user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)), *OR*
- When uploading the object, use `ACL='public-read'`, which will make the individual objects public

To make the bucket or objects public, you will also need to **disable S3 Block Public Access** on the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if the thumbnail is generated successfully
2. check your bucket has public accessibility enabled
3. check if the generated file thumbnail has public read permission